# Model lost on uniform background surface with ARCamera (Vuforia, Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to use Vuforia in Unity to see a model in AR. It is working properly when I'm in a room with lost of different colors, but if I go in a room with one single color (example : white floor, white wall, no furniture), the model keeps disappearing. I'm using Extended tracking with Prediction enabled.

Is there a way to keep the model on screen whatever the background seen by webcam?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to keep the model on screen whatever the background seen by webcam??

I am afraid this is not possible. Since vuforia uses [Markerless Tracking](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Markerless_Tracking) it requires high contrast on the points.

Since most of AR SDKs only use a monocular RGB camera (not RGB-Depth), they rely on computer vision techniques to calculate missing depth information. It means extracting visual distinct feature points and locating device using estimated distance to these feature points  over several frames while you move.

However, they also leverage from [sensor fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_tracking) which means they combine data gathered from camera and the data from IMU unit(sensors) of the device. Unfortunately, this data is mainly used for complementing when motion tracking fails in situations like excessive motion(when camera image is blurred). Therefore, sensor data itself is not reliable which is the case when you walk into a room where there are no distinctive points to extract.

The only way you can solve this is by placing several image targets in that room. That will allow Vuforia to calculate device position in 3D space. Otherwise this is not possible.

You can also refer to [SLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping) for more information.